# External drive connection error: Could not auto-redirect usbstick (permission denied)(3)

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, opensuse, qemu

I'm running `opensuse leap 15.4` on PC, I have installed `qemu` to run `windows 10` on it,the installation and configuration somehow went fine, but **when i try to connect external device** USB/HDD i get an **error**:

> "Could not auto-redirect usbstick ; failed to execute child process /usr/bin/spice-client-glib-usb-helper" (permission denied)(3).

Q: What could be the reason? Do I miss some configuration?

Thank you guys , after several attempt it worked fine , i'm now able to use all my external devices.

Comment: Welcome to the community. After a quick google search - verify your user is in libvirt and kvm groups; if not, add and restart session. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in OpenSuse Tumbleweed.
Virtualization was setup using Yast without any modifications on my part.

Solution was to simply add my user (pavin) to the requisite groups and reboot:

```
sudo usermod -a -G libvirt,qemu,kvm pavin
systemctl reboot
```